# How do I count letters occurring in a string without using a dictionary or list.count()?

Tags: python

I am trying to count each letter up without using `count()` or
`dict()`.

I did write something but I am still having issues with my code.

```
myString = []
#countList = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
myString ="pynativepynvepynative"
countList = [len(myString)+1]
for i in range(len(myString)):
        #print("Here 0")
        for j in range(len(countList)):
            #print("Here 1")
            if i == countList[j]:
                #print("Here 1.1")
                countList[j+1] = (countList[j+1] + 1)
                break
            else:
                #print("Here 2")
                countList.append(myString[i])
                countList.append(1)
                break
print(countList)
```

Expected output:

```
['p', 3, 'y', 3, 'n', 3, 'a', 2, 't', 2, 'i', 2, 'v', 3, 'e', 3]
```

Actual output:

```
[22, 'p', 1, 'y', 1, 'n', 1, 'a', 1, 't', 1, 'i', 1, 'v', 1, 'e', 1, 'p', 1, 'y', 1, 'n', 1, 'v', 1, 'e', 1, 'p', 1, 'y', 1, 'n', 1, 'a', 1, 't', 1, 'i', 1, 'v', 1, 'e', 1]
```

Comment: Are you trying to count the occurrence of each character? What is your expected output for this example?

Comment: So you would like to output a dictionary without using a dictionary?

Comment: Yes, if that is possible, just through manipulating a list

Comment: Your output is a dictionary @NoajmIsMyName you might want to change it to a list of tuples or something similar if you absolutely do not want to use a dict.

Comment: I don't see the point of manipulating a list if you would like to return a dictionary. Why not just use a dictionary from the beginning?

Comment: I am sorry  I copied that dict from the original question, sorry I did fix it

Comment: @adamgy you can always make a string that *looks* like a dictionary.

Comment: @smci There is a built-in `count()` for lists in Python. I think that may be what OP is wanting to avoid.

Comment: @gallen I do not see @ smci comment ... I guess he just dose like to edit and run like all other editors  in here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using my question code, I was able to get the right answer modifying the question's code

My problem was that I did not know how to initiate `countList` properly

```
countList = []
myString ="pynativepynvepynative"
for i in range(len(myString)):
        #print("Here 0")
        for j in range(len(countList)):
            #print("Here 1")
            #print(myString[i])
            #print(j)
            #print(countList[j])
            if myString[i] == countList[j]:
                #print("Here 1.1")
                #print(myString[i])
                countList[j+1] = (countList[j+1] + 1)
                break
        else :
            #print("Here 2")
            countList.append(myString[i])
            countList.append(1)
print(countList)
```

Actual output:

```
['p', 3, 'y', 3, 'n', 3, 'a', 2, 't', 2, 'i', 2, 'v', 3, 'e', 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

what can you do is get the unique letters from the string and the for each unique letter loop through the string to count its frequency.

```
def func_count(string):
    letter = []
    for char in string:
        if char not in letter:
            letter.append(char)
    res = []
    for let in letter:
        count = 0
        for char in string:
            if let == char:
                count+=1
        res.extend([let, count])
    # res = {a:b for a,b in zip(res[::2], res[1::2])} 
    return res

string = "pynativepynvepynative"

solution = func_count(string)
print(solution)
```

output

```
['p', 3, 'y', 3, 'n', 3, 'a', 2, 't', 2, 'i', 2, 'v', 3, 'e', 3]
```

edit, if you want solution in dict form add         `res = {a:b for a,b in zip(res[::2], res[1::2])}` in function

Answer (score 0):

Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), the dict subclass for counting objects, which makes this a one-liner:

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter('pynativepynvepynative')

Counter({'p': 3, 'y': 3, 'n': 3, 'v': 3, 'e': 3, 'a': 2, 't': 2, 'i': 2})
```

(Technically this isn't a dict, it's a subclass of dict.)

You can get a list-of-tuple from it:

```
>>> c.most_common()
[('p', 3), ('y', 3), ('n', 3), ('v', 3), ('e', 3), ('a', 2), ('t', 2), ('i', 2)]
```

**Lists or tuples are undesirable for counting things, because you want to be able to separately access/sort by the keys (objects that you're counting) and the values (counts).** In theory you can do that on list-of-list/tuple, but it's a pain, and `Counter` alrady defines several of the methods you'll need.

Comment: I truly do understand your point. I am only doing this example just to be better at looping and alternating elements inside a list... I am still learning!